# What is role="listbox" used when creating carousel?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-carousel

Just a simple question

When I tried to create a carousel, I noticed many sample codes are:

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
```

In the above code, what does **role="listbox"** do?
Please give me an insight.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**role="listbox"** is used for accessibility purposes. It identifies to a screen-reader or other assistive technology device that this is an element that allows a user to choose one or more options, such as images in a carousel.

You should also add **role="option"** to each slide.

see here for more information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_listbox_role